# Help with creating a bash code to compare two different files

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, diff, file-comparison

I'm currently encountering some challenges while working on a bash script in the Linux terminal to perform the following tasks:

1. Compare the values in the third column of two different files line by line.
2. If the values are different, save in a third output file the identifier from the second column of the input files, along with the corresponding values from both File 1 and File 2, similar to the "desired first output" example provided.
3. Additionally, create a fourth output file to tally the occurrences of each unique qualitative difference, taking into account the order (for example: 9690 0 ≠ 0 9690) while disregarding the identifier. This is illustrated in the "desired last output" example.

Any assistance or guidance in achieving this is greatly appreciated!

FILE 1

```
U   E100033877L1C016R01601996031        0   140 0:106
U   E100033877L1C023R03303214633        0   140 0:106
C   E100033877L1C022R01901579971        27996   140 27996:1 0:7 27996:23 0:75
C   E100033877L1C023R02603225407        27996   140 0:32 27996:23 0:7 27996:1 0:3 27996:4 0:36
C   E100033877L1C020R02602000209        0   140 0:106
C   E100033877L1C023R03303214633        27996   140 27996:3 0:4 27996:5 0:94
C   E100033877L1C023R03101740491        9690    140 9690:13 0:8 9690:7 0:13 9690:9 0:56
C   E100033877L1C006R00200498634        9690    140 9690:71 0:35
C   E100033877L1C009R03603066069        27996   140 0:50 27996:2 0:1 27996:10 0:6 27996:11 0:26
C   E100033877L1C005R03300436825        27996   140 27996:3 0:6 27996:3 0:3 27996:5 0:86
```

FILE2

```
U   E100033877L1C016R01601996031        0   140 0:106
U   E100033877L1C023R03303214633        0   140 0:106
C   E100033877L1C022R01901579971        27996   140 27996:1 0:7 27996:23 0:75
C   E100033877L1C023R02603225407        27996   140 0:32 27996:23 0:7 27996:1 0:3 27996:4 0:36
C   E100033877L1C020R02602000209        27996   140 0:19 27996:4 0:3 27996:1 0:7 27996:23 0:49
C   E100033877L1C023R03303214633        27996   140 27996:3 0:4 27996:5 0:94
U   E100033877L1C023R03101740491        0   140 0:106
U   E100033877L1C006R00200498634        0   140 4840:106
C   E100033877L1C009R03603066069        4840    140 0:50 27996:2 0:1 27996:10 0:6 27996:11 0:26
C   E100033877L1C005R03300436825        27996   140 27996:3 0:6 27996:3 0:3 27996:5 0:86
```

DESIRED FIRST OUTPUT

```
E100033877L1C020R02602000209        0   27996
E100033877L1C023R03101740491        9690    0   
E100033877L1C006R00200498634        9690    0   
E100033877L1C009R03603066069        27996   4840
```

DISIRED LAST OUTPUT

```
2   9690    0   
1   0   27996
1   27996   4840
```

Comment: Reads like a homework assignment; you've not show us your attempt at it, and where you're having problems.

Comment: The cross-post on Ask Ubuntu has been closed, please don't vote to close this as cross-posted.

Comment: Why are `E100033877L1C023R03303214633 27996 0` and `E100033877L1C023R03303214633 0 27996` missing from your output?

Comment: Please tell us How you are trying?